# How to run NativeScript app in Windows using Visual Studio Emulator?

Tags: nativescript

How to run NativeScript app in Windows using Visual Studio Emulator?
trying to get this project:

https://github.com/avatsaev/nativescript-master-detail-angular2

to run in Windows 10 64bit visual studio emulator but always android emulator is launching instead when running:

this is my adb devices:

```
List of devices attached
169.254.138.177:5555    device
```

tns livesync android --emulator --watch

also tried

tns livesync 169.254.138.177:5555 --emulator --watch

no luck!

regards

Sean

Comment: This is my detailed answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774657/nativescript-project-running-with-visual-studio-emulator/47830796#47830796 ♥

Answer (score 5):

found the answer

```
 tns run android --device 169.254.138.177:5555
```

and you get the device from:

```
adb devices
```

enjoy!

Comment: hi @born2net, You can also use `tns device` to list the available emulator and devices

Comment: tx! appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 3):

If the emulator is already running and visible with `adb devices` - you can just run `tns run android`. This will build and deploy on all visible devices. Same is valid for `tns livesync android`.