# Nativescript project running with Visual Studio Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-code, nativescript, visual-studio-emulator

I have a Nativescript application that I'm developing using VS Code and have no issues when I try to run it using the Nativescript launch configurations from the Nativescript extension, when I'm using a real device connected with USB or when I use one of the android-sdk emulators.

Now I need to run Hyper-V on the machine too and those emulators cannot run when hypervisor is on. So I downloaded and installed Visual Studio Android Emulator which runs fine when I launch it manually.

Problem is that the nativescript project doesn't recognize this device either with tns device or adb devices commands and if I try to launch the application from VS Code it tries to launch one of the other emulators, which obviously fails due to the hypervisor/Intel Haax incompatibility.

Did any of you had this problem before and have any solutions you can share?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Microsoft MSDN say :

**If the emulator is running, but it does not appear to be connected to ADB** or it does not appear in Android tools that make use of ADB `(for example, Android Studio or Eclipse)`, you may need to adjust where the emulator looks for ADB.

The emulator uses ***a registry key*** to identify the base **location of your Android SDK**, and looks for the ***\platform-tools\adb.exe*** file under that directory.

---

**Here We Go!! Step By Step ;)**

Copy Your `ANDROID SDK PATH` for me it look like this :

[image]

---

To modify the Android SDK path used by the emulator:

1. Open Registry Editor by selecting Run from the Start buttons context menu, typing **`regedit`** in the dialog box, and choosing OK.

[image]

---

2. Navigate to **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Android SDK Tools`** in the folder tree on the left.

> Note : if `Android SDK Tools` folder doesn't exist, Create it under `WOW6432Node`, And open it, And Create a `String Value` name it `Path`:)

3. Modify the **`Path`** registry variable to match the path to your **`Android SDK`**.

[image]

---

4. Restart the emulator and you should now be able to see the emulator connected to ADB and associated Android tools.

[image]

---

Now! Open Your Terminal (CMD), and Run ADB command

`adb devices -l`

[image]

**YES YES !! The Visual Studio Emulator is running, and connected to ADB!**

---

**HERE WE GOO !!**

Now We Want To Create A Demo App (for example FIRSTZAKI) *ZAKI is my nickname* :p

On Terminal (CMD) :

`tns create FIRSTZAKI`

[image]

Choose Android Platform

`cd FIRSTZAKI\`

`tns platform add android`

[image]

Check if VS EMULATOR is ready!

`tns devices`

[image]

**YES YES ^^**

Finally Step **(RUN/BUILD)** :

`tns run android`

[image]

**WOW ... Great :)**

[image]

AND .. Good Luck ♥ — ZAKI

Comment: You 're a little god !

Comment: Sorry ^^! what do you mean

Comment: you saved me lot's of time of searching how to setup Visual studio emulator properly ... nice job

Comment: I'm glad to help you ^^

Comment: Sadly i can't get this to work, i installed the SDK with android studio so its located under "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk", i have added the registry entry but the emulator, the "adb devices -l" still yields a empty list, i have restarted both the server and the entire computer, i have tried multiple android images in the emulator.