# Is it possible to use the visual studio emulator with vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-emulator

Visual Studio Code reports "No Devices" when I run a device from the Visual Studio Emulator for Android.

Is there a way to make this work?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a very common bug that's normally fixed with a regedit.

See ['Visual Studio Emulator for Android' devices are not listed in the Android Device Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088648/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-devices-are-not-listed-in-the-android-devic?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [Nativescript project running with Visual Studio Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774657/nativescript-project-running-with-visual-studio-emulator), which refer to the fix outlined by Microsft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/troubleshooting-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android?view=vs-2015#ADB